# How to identify that STAF finished initialization?

Tags: frameworks, automation, automated-tests, startup

How to identify that STAF is fully up and ready after a reboot?  We currently use "staf local ping ping", but this command returns "pong" even before STAF is fully ready for other commands.
Preferably I need something that would be platform independent (ok for Win, Linux, etc.). Thanks!